# MySQL: Copying foreign keys only

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, export

I've recently duplicated a database to a dev instance, and after doing a bunch of work on it realized that it's missing the foreign key constraints of the original database. The indexes were included. Can I create an export script from the original DB which *only* includes the foreign keys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd ask why didn't it create the foreign keys on your dev instance? Are you creating the tables as MyISAM tables? MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys, so you certainly won't be able to create them even if you can isolate the right definitions.

You can identify the changes needed using `mysqldbcompare`, which is a tool provided in the free [MySQL Utilities](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/).

For example, I created a `test` database with a table `foo` and a child table `bar` with a foreign key referencing `foo`. I duplicated the `test` database to a `test2` database (still on localhost). Then I dropped the foreign key in the `test2.bar` table, so there's a difference.

I can use mysqldbcompare to detect this difference and output the required ALTER TABLE to recreate the foreign key:

```
mysqldbcompare 
  --server1=root:password@localhost 
  --server2=root:password@localhost 
  --difftype=sql 
  --run-all-tests 
  --changes-for=server2 
  test:test2
```

In my case, both database are on my localhost instance, but they could be on different servers. I would just specify the servers in the `--server1` and `--server2` options.

`--difftype=sql` means to output SQL statements to bring the two databases into sync.  `--changes-for=server2` means I want server2 to change to match the other.

`test:test2` name the databases to compare. If they're on different servers, they may both have the same database name.

Here's the output:

```
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# server2 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases test on server1 and test2 on server2
#
#                                                   Defn    Row     Data   
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# TABLE     bar                                     FAIL    pass    -       
#           - Compare table checksum                                FAIL    
#           - Find row differences                                  pass    
#
# Transformation for --changes-for=server2:
#

ALTER TABLE `test2`.`bar` 
ADD CONSTRAINT bar_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY(foo_id) REFERENCES `test`.`foo`(id);


# TABLE     foo                                     pass    pass    -       
#           - Compare table checksum                                FAIL    
#           - Find row differences                                  pass   

# Database consistency check failed.
#
# ...done
```

It looks like it'll try to create the FK to reference the old database name `test`. If I used this, it wouldn't do what I want, so I'd have to edit this before I run it. If you're comparing a copy on a different server, maybe the database name didn't change, so it would just work.

By default it also compares the data in each table, but there are options to skip those tests.

Read the documentation for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html

Comment: Thank you for this! I was able to get it to output a script similar in syntax to your example, but it yields errors. For example, ADD CONSTRAINT activities_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY(meetingID) REFERENCES `abcd-testing`.`groupMeetings`(id) gets " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_ibfk_3,"

Comment: I've never seen MySQL report a syntax error in the *middle* of a token. I'd recommend you make sure you typed it correctly, and didn't accidentally add white space or punctuation in the middle of the constraint name.